# Load object from REST before Form is validated/shown?

Tags: angularjs

I'm taking a peek at angularjs and currently i'm creating a html form to update a object in the database.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="folder.title" name="title" size="30" required>
```

When the page that contain the form loads the field has a red border, this is because of the required tag.

I have a controller that gets the object from a rest service and binds is to the "folder" object in the scope:

```
$scope.master = Folder.get({
            folderId : $routeParams.folderId
        }, function() {
            $scope.reset();
        });
$scope.reset = function() {
            $scope.folder = angular.copy($scope.master);
        };
```

This works quite nicely. The only problem is that when i load the page in my browser the browser thinks that the form field is invalid and displays the red border. After less than a second the folder object is returned from the REST service and is bound to the $scope.folder. Now the border of the form field turns from red to white, because it is now valid.

How can i make sure that the folder object is loaded in the scope before the form is displayed?

I do use ngroute to decide which view will be displayed:

```
myApp.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/folders', {
        ...
    }).when('/folders/:folderId', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/folder-details.html',
        controller : 'FolderDetailCtrl'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/folders'
    });
} ]);
```

Comment: If your form isn't dirty, you can add `.ng-pristine { border: 1px solid black; }` to your css.

Comment: I've added the css you suggested and bound it to my form, it doesn't seem to solve the problem, the red blinking field is still there. But thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but per the docs, you can take advantage of the ngRequired directive to accomplish this (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="folder.title" name="title" size="30" ng-required="restLoaded">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.restLoaded=false;
$scope.master = Folder.get({
        folderId : $routeParams.folderId
    }, function() {
        $scope.restLoaded=true;
        $scope.reset();
    });
```

Comment: I did not yet know the ng-required directive, i've replaced required with ng-required and added a restloaded tag to my controller and now the blinking red field is gone. Thanks for the simple solution ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use resolve in your ng-route  to make sure the form data is loaded before the view is rendered. Keep in mind this will hold up the entire view, not just the form, but this might be what you want.

Comment: I have not yet been able to try this one, but it does sound like a good solution, loading the data before showing the form makes sense and will prevent the user from seeing a empty form and a second later a filled form. I will need to do a bit research on how to implement this the best way. Cheers for your suggestion.